# Primary constraints for Hamiltonian field theories

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory, constrained-dynamics

I am currently trying to carry out the construction of the generalised Hamiltonian, constraints and constraint algebra, etc for a particular field theory following the procedure in Dirac's "Lectures on quantum mechanics". My question is the following:

I have momentum variables that depend on the spatial derivatives of the generalised coordinates, but not on the time derivatives of the generalised coordinates. Is this a primary constraint or not?

I have conflicting thoughts on this. On the one hand, there are texts that say a primary constraint occurs when the definition of a momentum variable is not invertible for the corresponding velocity. By this criteria, I do have a primary constraint because the momentum does not depend on the time derivative of the generalised coordinates.

On the other hand, Dirac for example says that a primary constraint is a function of the form

$\chi(p,q)=0$

that comes from the definition of the momenta. This is not the case for me, since I have a function that also depends on the spatial derivatives of the q's. By this criteria, I don't have a primary constraint.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering [Hamiltonian formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics), it is important to distinguish between the following two frameworks:

1. **Point mechanics** (PM). Variables$^1$: $q^i(t)$ and $p_j(t)$. The Hamiltonian $H$ depends on the following arguments: $$\tag{1} H(q(t);p(t);t).$$
2. **Field theory** (FT) in $d+1$ spacetime dimensions. Variables$^1$: $\phi^{\alpha}(x,t)$ and $\pi_{\beta}(x,t)$. The Hamiltonian density ${\cal H}$ depends on the following arguments:
   $${\cal H}\left(\phi(x,t), \partial \phi(x,t),\partial^2\phi(x,t),\ldots,\partial^N\phi(x,t) ;\right. $$ 
   $$\tag{2}\left. \pi(x,t) , \partial \pi(x,t),\partial^2\pi(x,t),\ldots,\partial^N\pi(x,t)  ;x,t\right).$$
   where $\partial$ denotes spatial (as opposed to temporal) derivative. Here $N$ is finite for a local FT, and $N\leq 1$ for a relativistic FT.

PM is the $d=0$ case of FT; while FT can be viewed as PM if we treat spatial coordinates as a continuous index $i=(\alpha,x)$, cf. [DeWitt's condensed notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation).

FT always has infinitely many degrees of freedom (DOF), while PM could have finitely or infinitely many DOFs.

In the Legendre transformation/Dirac-Bergmann procedure for FT, the spatial derivatives (unlike the temporal derivatives) have no special status/role. Equivalently, the spatial derivatives are passive spectators.

In FT the definition of [primary constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint) carries over from the PM case without modification. In particular, the presence of spatial derivatives doesn't alter the status of an equation as a constraint or not.

--

$^1$ Note that in the case of constraints, the variables (besides dynamical variables) include auxiliary variables as well.

Comment: So, using your notation, in the field theory case if I had a momentum given by $\pi = \partial \phi$, would that be a primary constraint? I am inclined to answer no, because it seems to me this simply determines the variable $\partial \phi$ in terms of $\pi$, and does not reduce the number of independent variables in the phase space.

Comment: Moreover, if my example is indeed a primary constraint, then how does one go about imposing it? The primary constraints should define a constraint surface in the phase space, but $\pi - \partial \phi =0$ does not do that.

Comment: @Steven: Yes e.g. the model ${\cal L}=\dot{\phi} \partial \phi$ leads to the primary constraint $\pi = \partial \phi$. What FT are you looking at? What is the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$?

Comment: The theory that I'm actually dealing with can be found in section 2 of the following paper:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1660.

I am working with the four dimensional version of this theory (things are qualitatively different for dimensions $\leq$ 3). It is a 'pure gauge' theory that is equivalent to the first order form of general relativity. The momentum conjugate to the $\phi$ and the spatial part of $\omega$ (spin connection) variables involve spatial derivatives of $\phi$ and $\omega$, but do not depend on the corresponding velocities.

Comment: To save you some time, the momentum conjugate to $\phi^a$ for example is given by $\pi_a = 2 (D_j \phi)^b F_{kl}^{cd} \epsilon_{abcd} \epsilon^{jkl}$. The indices $i,j,k=1,2,3$ are "spacetime" indices that are restricted to run over the space part. $D$ is the covariant derivative for the gauge group, which is $ISO(4)$, F is the field strength tensor, and the indices $a,b,c,d...=1,2,3,4$ are in a particular representation of the four dimensional Euclidean group $ISO(4)$.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think momenta of this form do not lead to primary constraints. For example, carrying out the constraint analysis using the Faddeev-Jackiw approach ([pdf](http://srv2.fis.puc.cl/~mbanados/Cursos/TopicosRelatividadAvanzada/FaddeevJackiw.pdf)) does not give these as primary constraints. And if you try to treat them as if they were, as far as I can see it leads to inconsistencies. Finally, by Dirac's definition in the "lectures on quantum mechanics", they are not constraints because they are not functions of the form $\chi(q,p)=0$.

Comment: Therefore I think the answer should be modified; the definition of primary constraint does indeed carry over to the field theory case unchanged so long as that definition is taken to be "A function of the form $\chi(q,p) = 0$ that arises from the definition of the momenta". In particular, a function of the form $\chi(q,p,\partial q) = 0$ is ${\it not}$ a constraint.

Comment: @Steven: Please also include explicitly the action/Lagrangian density to make sure we talk about the same model. I guess it is a (3+1)D Pagels model with $ISO(4)$ gauge group packed inside $SO(5)$ with a fixed preferred gauge direction?

Comment: The 4d action is $\int (D\phi)^A \wedge (D\phi)^B \wedge F^{CD} \epsilon_{ABCDE} \phi^E$. The gauge group may be taken to be $SO(5)$ or $ISO(4)$ (the form of the action is the same). The difference is that the cosmological constant is $0$ for $ISO(4)$ and non-zero for $SO(5)$.

Comment: Correction to the answer (v3): The last $N$ in equation (2) should be $N-1$.

Comment: What if we have a function $\chi(p,q^i)=0$ of a single momentum $p$ and coordinates $q^i$ which are *not* conjugate to $p$, which comes from the definition of the momentum $p$. Does that alter the function's status as a primary constraint?